# How do I force detach Screen from another SSH session?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, gnu-screen

I had Screen running inside an SSH session.  Terminal froze.  After restarting Terminal, that Screen session still thinks it's attached.  Maybe it is.  Perhaps I don't really know what that means.

I'd like to attach to that Screen session from a fresh SSH login.  I do not want to kill that Screen session as important things are happening over there.  : )

The options I think I have ( none of which I know how to solve ):

- How do I detach that Screen session?
- How do I kill the SSH session that that Screen session is attached to?

Answer (score 366, accepted):

As Jose answered, `screen -d -r` should do the trick. This is a combination of two commands, as taken from the man page.

`screen -d` detaches the already-running screen session, and `screen -r` reattaches the existing session. By running `screen -d -r`, you force screen to detach it and then resume the session.

If you use the capital `-D -RR`, I quote the man page because it's too good to pass up.

> Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it.
>
> > Note: It is always a good idea to check the status of your sessions by means of "screen -list".

Comment: You can also do `screen -x` which is faster to type, but not entirely equivalent. It will attach the session a second time without detaching first, resulting in multi display mode.

Comment: remember "Screen Doctor"; `screen -Dr`

Answer (score 64):

try with `screen -d -r` or `screen -D -RR`

Answer (score 15):

## Short answer

1. Reattach without ejecting others: `screen -x`
2. Get list of displays: `^A` `*`, select the one to disconnect, press `d`

---

## Explained answer

**Background:** When I was looking for the solution with same problem description, I have always landed on this answer. I would like to provide more sensible solution. *(For example: the other attached screen has a different size and a I cannot force resize it in my terminal.)*

> *Note:* `PREFIX` is usually `^A` = `ctrl+a`

> *Note:* the **display** may also be called:
>
> - **"user front-end"** (in `at` command manual in screen)
> - **"client"** (tmux vocabulary where this functionality is `detach-client`)
> - **"terminal"** (as we call the window in our user interface) /depending on

**1. Reattach a *session*: `screen -x`**

`-x` attach to a not detached screen session *without detaching it*

**2. List *displays* of this session: `PREFIX` `*`**

It is the default key binding for: `PREFIX` `:displays`. 
Performing it within the screen, identify the other *display* we want to disconnect (e.g. smaller size). (Your current *display* is displayed in brighter color/bold *when not selected*).

```
term-type   size         user interface           window       Perms
---------- ------- ---------- ----------------- ----------     -----
 screen     240x60         you@/dev/pts/2      nb  0(zsh)        rwx
 screen      78x40         you@/dev/pts/0      nb  0(zsh)        rwx
```

Using arrows `↑` `↓`, select the targeted *display*, press `d`
If nothing happens, you tried to detach your own display and screen will not detach it. If it was another one, within a second or two, the entry will disappear.

Press `ENTER` to quit the listing.

*Optionally:* in order to make the content fit your screen, *reflow*: `PREFIX` `F` (uppercase F)

**Excerpt from man page of screen:**

> displays
>
> Shows a tabular listing of all currently connected user front-ends (displays).  This is most useful for multiuser sessions.  The following keys can be used in displays list:
>
> - `mouseclick` Move to the selected line. Available when "mousetrack" is set to on.
> - `space` Refresh the list
> - `d` Detach that display
> - `D` Power detach that display
> - `C-g`, `enter`, or `escape` Exit the list